# player.on('play', function() also executes on pause and replay

Tags: javascript, php

For starters, my knowledge of javascript is not so great. But I have managed to implement a script that sends an email when my users start a video. For your information: It is a private location after login, so it is not a public website.

The problem is with this script it does not only send an e-mail on start of the video, it also sends an e-mail every time the user presses the pause and play button during watching the video. I only want to know when the video is started from the beginning of the video. So not every time it is paused and started again. Is this possible? And if so, how do I do this? Thanks so much for your help.

```
`<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<script>
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);
player.on('play', function() {
   window.open("https://mywebsitelocation”, “myiframe”);
});
</script>`
```

Comment: I don't know how these Vimeo events work, but I'd guess that it's likely there's an event value, such that your function can be written `player.on('play', function(event) {...`, and that event would likely carry information about the current play state, including time offset. If my guess is correct, you could trigger the email only when the play starts from time 0.

Comment: I see a combination of straight and smart quotes in your code. If you are using that same code in production, it will cause errors. Only use unformatted characters in code.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the Vimeo API after I made my comment, and I think this should work:

```
player.on('play', function(event) {
    if (event.seconds === 0) {
        window.open('https://mywebsitelocation', 'myiframe');
    }
});
```

Since there is a separate `pause` event in the API, I am a bit surprised that the above callback is triggered, as you say, when the player is paused too.

Perhaps if you add something like this:

`player.on('pause', function() {});`

...so that there's a separate do-nothing callback for `pause`, the `play` callback won't be triggered for pause.

Comment: Will probably open the popup if they restart the video as well.  To do it right you will prob need a global "hasPopupBeenOpened" boolean that gets set in the play handler.